# Perl regex for checking an element from a URL

Tags: regex, perl, url

There is a sample URL like this

```
http://ipaddress.com:1020/hello/index.php?module=Cases&action=HelloView&record=65hj3bn4-e63a-fedb-7783-132247bcg06d
```

From this URL I need to extract the part `65hj3bn4-e63a-fedb-7783-132247bcg06d` after `record=`

I tried these

```
1)  ::http\://[0-9.]+\:[0-9]{4}/[a-zA-Z]+/[a-z.]+[a-z]{3}?\+[a-z]+=(.*)::([a-z0-9]+\-[a-z0-9]+\-[a-z0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[a-z0-9]+)::

2) ::((((ht|f)tp(s?))\://){1}\S+)::(\d){2}::

3) (http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: IPaddress.com , is not the full domain address, I mentioned it like that, since, the validation is not letting me giving sample IP address in it. It is actually a numeric IP in place of ipaddress.com please help

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged. 

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Why match the whole thing? Just pull out the record parameter

```
my ($record) = $url =~ /record=([\w-]*)&?/;
```

As Borodin suggests below, it would make more sense to not match the trailing &:

```
my ($record) = $url =~ /\brecord=([^&]*)/
```

or better yet use a module that is designed to pull out query parameters [`URI::QueryParam`](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI/URI/QueryParam.pm)

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

use URI;
use URI::QueryParam; 

my $url = 'http://ipaddress.com:1020/hello/index.php?' 
    . 'module=Cases&action=HelloView&record=65hj3bn4-e63a-fedb-7783-132247bcg06d';
my $uri = URI->new($url);

my $record = $uri->query_param('record');
print "Record Value: $record\n";
```

Comment: In the first part of the answer, `/record=(\w*)&?/` will match only `record=65hj3bn4`, since `\w` doesn't match `-`.

Comment: @FilippoLauria Thanks, I always forget that class doesn't include a hyphen

Comment: There is no point at all in matching an optional `&` at the end. You should take your own advice and avoid matching stuff outside what you want! I would prefer `/\brecord=([^&]*)/` as there is a lot of stuff other than alphanumerics, underscore and hyphen that could validly appear there.

Answer (score 0):

this is maybe to easy, but what about

```
record=([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)
```

Comment: What if other query parameters follow record?

Comment: actually the pattern `[a-zA-Z0-0]` can be compressed to `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one `record=((?:\w+\-?)+)`.

PS. the interested part is in the first capture group.
So if you're using `perl` you could do something like this:

```
 ...
my $str = "http://ipaddress:1020/hello/index.php?record=65hj3bn4-e63a-fedb-7783-132247bcg06d&module=Cases&action=HelloView&";
my ($part) =  $str =~ /record=((?:\w+\-?)+)/;
print $part;
 ...
```

That will output: `65hj3bn4-e63a-fedb-7783-132247bcg06d`

Comment: Thanks.I tried this code for the url : http://128.128.128.128:8080/ex.php?le=Cas&action=Deew&record=65fa3ce4-e63a-fedb-2883-534237bcd06a, but It didn't match. Expected result is "65fa3ce4-e63a-fedb-2883-534237bcd06a"